# LuaLaTeX: Calculate length in Lua

Tags: luatex, calculations, lengths, directlua

I apologize if this a rookie question, but I find it extremely hard to find a solution to my Lua problem using online searches and browsing reference manuals.

I would like to calculate a length: Divide `\linewidth` by `\baselineskip`, take the `floor`, and finally multiply with `\baselineskip`. The result should be returned in `pt`.

I already fail with getting `\baselineskip` into Lua such that I can do a calculation with it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Linewidth works this way: \directlua{tex.sprint(tex.dimen['linewidth'] / 65536)tex.sprint('pt')}
\item and this way: \directlua{tex.sprint(tex.dimen.linewidth / 65536)tex.sprint('pt')}
\item \directlua{tex.sprint(tex.dimen['baselineskip'])}
\item \directlua{tex.print(tex.skip['baselineskip'].width)}
\item \directlua{tex.print(tex.skip['baselineskip'].stretch)}
\item \directlua{tex.sprint(tex.baselineskip)}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

So the questions are: How do I get `\baselineskip` into Lua, and how can I calculate and output the length I described above.

If someone happens to know a "real" beginner's guide to LuaLaTeX that also discusses such problems, I would appreciate a hint. Thanks!

---

### Solution

With the help of the answers below, the length above can be calculated as:

```
\directlua{tex.sprint(math.floor(tex.dimen.linewidth / tex.baselineskip.width)
    * tex.baselineskip.width  / tex.sp('1pt') ..'pt')}
```

Comment: @HenriMenke This causes an error: `[\directlua]:1: incorrect dimen name stack traceback:
 [C]: in function 'getdimen'
 [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
l.9 ...lua{tex.sprint(tex.getdimen("baselineskip"))}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `tex.baselineskip` in Lua to get the baselineskip but a skip is a Lua userdata object (as it has stretch and shrink components as well as a natural length) so you can not directly use it in inline arithmetic Lua expressions with `/`

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\directlua{
print('baseline is '  ..tex.baselineskip.width)
}
\end{document}
```

produces terminal output:

```
baseline is 786432
```

Comment: Is there a way to convert it to a number that one can use in a calculation? Or does this mean it is not possible?

Comment: @FlorianL - Just write `tex.baselineskip.width/65536` if you want the length expressed in `pt` units instead of `sp` units.

Comment: @FlorianL yes exactly the .width is a number what I meant is that tex.baselineskip itself is a userdata thing.  The width field is just a normal Lua integer (786432 here)

Comment: You can also do `tex.baselineskip.width/tex.sp("1pt")` if you don't want to memorize that 1pt = 65536sp.